# CSS3 animation. Radar style similar to the 'Tinder' app

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to create an animation that acts somewhat similar to a radar effect, similar to the 'Tinder' app.

It is very similar to what I have done in the fiddle, with a bit of fine tuning, which is where I need some help!

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/33w67/4/

Essentially from 0% - 90% I want the circle to expand while the inner div slowly fades away.

90% - 100% I want the div to continue to grow, but fade to an opacity of 0 in that timeframe.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        top:200px;
    }
    90% {
        width:870px;
        height:870px;
        top:-160px;
    }
    100% {
        width:950px;
        height:950px;
        top:-200px;
    }
}
```

Also, the infinite aspect of it. I would like it so it looks as if a pulse is emmited ever n seconds, as opposed to a pulse on pulse completion. Originally I had used jQuery to add and remove elements on a timeout() but it wasn't very efficient. Right now it's using multiple divs, which is also kind of crappy.

Any advice is much appreicated, thank you!!

Comment: Can you provide what the Tinder radar looks like? I'm not familiar with it

Comment: I tried but I could only find their old versions. Where it expands, stops, expands and fade I want to get all into one smooth animation. Where there is no stoppage before the opacity goes to 0.

Answer (score 3):

[**How does this look?**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/33w67/6/)

I cleaned up a good bit of your code, removing some unecessary HTML elements, combining CSS code, adding missing semicolons (*You should still include them even if  it's the last CSS line for future purposes!*), and fixed your animation.

The main thing that I changed is that you list only **some** CSS properties in a keyframe and any previous ones will remain. This means you can have just one change in size but have opacity end sooner.

```
/* HTML */
<section id='slide4'>
    <img src='http://www.ribbustingjokes.com/lilsusieq/scrapbook/frames/circle/frame_circle_A_1.png' style='width:178px'/>
    <div id='pulse1'></div>
    <div id='pulse2'></div>
</section>

/* CSS webkit prefixes left out for brevity (they're in demo) */
body { width:1280px; overflow-y:hidden; }
img { 
    position:absolute; 
    top:50%; left:50%; 
    z-index:1; 
    transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
#pulse1, #pulse2 {
    border-radius:50%;
    position:absolute;
    height: 150px; width: 150px;
    top: 50%; left:50%;
    border: 2px solid rgba(66, 152, 181, 1);
    animation: pulsate 3s infinite;
    background-color:#4298b5;
    transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
#pulse2 {
    animation: pulsate 3s -.5s infinite;
}
@keyframes pulsate {
    0%,100% {
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
        opacity:0;
    }
    1% { opacity:1; }
    70% {
        opacity:0.5;
    }
    99.999% {
        width:950px;
        height:950px;
        opacity:0;
    }
}
```

I also fixed an issue with the full color flashing in at the end of the animation by holding off the start of the opacity animation until 1%

I also changed the second animation to use a negative animation delay so it starts immediately. Check out [my article](http://css-tricks.com/css-animation-tricks/) for more information on the subject

I also used `transformX(-50%) transformY(-50%)` to perfectly center the objects, which translates it have of the width and height of the element left and up

I hope it helps!